# Update User Meta with spaces using REST API - WordPress

Tags: wordpress, rest, api

I'm trying to update the user meta with spaces registered on my website. I am using `register_meta` hook to register user meta. And for updating users using WordPress REST API I use `wp_remote_post` but the problem is when I tried to update a user meta with spaces it will add as array in response then it will add as new user meta.

For example the value of user meta is - community test

Sample Response:

```
[meta] => Array
          (               
          [agent_community] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => community
                                [1] => test
                            )
           )
```

Sample Code for registering user meta.

```
register_meta('user', 'agent_community', array(
  "type" => "string",
  "show_in_rest" => true
));
```

Update using wp_remote_post

```
$update_data = array('email'=> 'test@mail.com', 'meta[agent_community]' => 'community test');
$args = array(
        'headers' => array(
                    'Authorization' => 'Basic ' . base64_encode( 'username:password' ),
            ),
            'body' => array_filter($update_data));
$update_url = 'https://test-url.com/wp-json/wp/v2/users/17';
$response = wp_remote_post( $update_url, $args);
```

Database:
[image]

Is there a way that can merge the array on user meta?

Answer (score 0):

[implode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) might help you. And you can change spaces with HTML entities. Or use function like `urledncode() / urlendecode()` or something like this.

Comment: Yes I also tried that but it will give me %20. I already have an answer. it must be meta[agent_community][0] = 'community test'. adding 0 index.